# Home Cat5 questions

Tags: rj-45, cat5

The house I'm working on has pre wires cat5 going through it, but they didnt terminate any wall plates. They all centrally meet in the basement. The demarc unfortunately comes in upstairs. The modem, and router are upstairs as well. I have a single run going from upstairs to downstairs ("home run"). I have terminated the wall plates using B like all my cables.

When I terminate the "home run" downstairs, I'd like to just throw a RJ45 end on it and plug it into a switch instead of using a punch panel. What changes do I need to make on the RJ45 end to make the home run go from the wall upstairs directly to the basement switch?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to terminate it correctly - so ANSI/TIA-568-B on a rj45 plug.

It maybe easier to pull a premade cable instead, and cut the end off terminating it into your wall socket, as this does mean you won't then have to invest in a rj45 crimper. Or terminate it to a wall socket, as then you have the option of different lengths of cable from the socket to the device, as well as not accidently 'pulling' the cable when it's within the wall.